# how to close the avd in the linux os

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I am new to the android programming and my working environment is eclipse helio in the linux, Ubuntu 11.0.4.

Every time I start the avd via eclipse, I can not close or even control the avd no-matter graphically or by command.

And I have a idea, I need to find out the process of the current avd and try to kill it by command, but for the sake that I do not know the name or pid of the process, I can not kill it via that way.

here is the detail after I run the command:

```
ps aux

kaiwii@kaiwiiho:~$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   3044  1888 ?        Ss   16:22   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [migration/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [migration/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [migration/2]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [migration/3]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kworker/3:0]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [cpuset]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [khelper]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [netns]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kblockd]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kacpid]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [khubd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [md]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   16:22   0:00 [ksmd]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [aio]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthr]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [crypto]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kworker/u:2]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kworker/u:3]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kmpathd]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kmpath_handle]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kondemand]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:22   0:00 [kconservative]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:01 [kworker/1:1]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kworker/3:1]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kworker/2:1]
root       233  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [kjournald]
root       250  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:22   0:00 [flush-8:0]
root       284  0.0  0.0   2796  1184 ?        S    16:23   0:00 upstart-udev-br
syslog     363  0.0  0.0  28628  1624 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 rsyslogd -c4
root       377  0.0  0.0   3004  1156 ?        S<s  16:23   0:00 udevd --daemon
102        410  0.0  0.0   3472  1824 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 dbus-daemon --s
root       523  0.0  0.0   3008  1028 ?        S<   16:23   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       524  0.0  0.0   3008  1028 ?        S<   16:23   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       545  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:23   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       605  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    16:23   0:04 [kworker/0:3]
avahi      663  0.0  0.0   3148  1464 ?        S    16:23   0:00 avahi-daemon: r
avahi      664  0.0  0.0   3016   432 ?        S    16:23   0:00 avahi-daemon: c
root       690  0.0  0.0   2412   600 ?        S    16:23   0:00 upstart-socket-
root       711  0.0  0.1  18268  4396 ?        Ssl  16:23   0:00 NetworkManager
root       715  0.0  0.0   4660  2512 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem
root       718  0.0  0.1  23248  3584 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
root       726  0.0  0.1  18200  3596 ?        Ssl  16:23   0:00 gdm-binary
root       749  0.0  0.1  27088  3320 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/conso
root       752  0.0  0.0   5176  1764 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /sbin/wpa_suppl
root       818  0.0  0.1  19960  3908 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gd
root       828  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:23   0:00 [hd-audio0]
root       839  3.6  0.9  38160 27236 tty7     Ss+  16:23   4:21 /usr/bin/X :0 -
root       882  0.0  0.0   6792  2772 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd
root       952  0.0  0.0   1872   576 tty4     Ss+  16:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root       957  0.0  0.0   1872   580 tty5     Ss+  16:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1004  0.0  0.0   1872   580 tty2     Ss+  16:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1005  0.0  0.0   1872   576 tty3     Ss+  16:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1007  0.0  0.0   1872   576 tty6     Ss+  16:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1012  0.0  0.0   1864   680 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 acpid -c /etc/a
daemon    1013  0.0  0.0   2132   348 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 atd
root      1014  0.0  0.0   2268   872 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 cron
root      1016  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   16:23   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-cle]
root      1036  0.0  0.0   3156   652 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqba
root      1139  0.0  0.1  61708  4648 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/libvi
root      1147  0.0  0.0   5864  1816 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/postfi
root      1151  0.0  0.1  18312  3352 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gd
kaiwii    1238  0.0  0.2  36776  7568 ?        Ssl  16:23   0:00 gnome-session -
nobody    1248  0.0  0.0   2924   956 ?        S    16:23   0:00 dnsmasq --stric
uml-net   1262  0.0  0.0   1844   248 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/bin/uml_sw
kaiwii    1292  0.0  0.0   3368   192 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-ag
kaiwii    1295  0.0  0.0   3456   568 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-l
kaiwii    1301  0.1  0.0   5104  2340 ?        Ss   16:23   0:07 //bin/dbus-daem
kaiwii    1314  0.0  0.1   9904  4568 ?        S    16:23   0:01 /usr/lib/libgco
kaiwii    1328  0.0  0.1  42980  3288 ?        SLl  16:23   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
kaiwii    1331  0.0  0.3 101224 11708 ?        Ssl  16:23   0:02 /usr/lib/gnome-
postfix   1361  0.0  0.0   5924  1704 ?        S    16:23   0:00 qmgr -l -t fifo
kaiwii    1373  0.0  0.0   7872  2436 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
kaiwii    1377  2.5  1.5 185104 47548 ?        Sl   16:23   3:00 compiz
kaiwii    1379  1.2  0.1 161320  5872 ?        S<sl 16:23   1:27 /usr/bin/pulsea
rtkit     1382  0.0  0.0  19912  1216 ?        SNl  16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/
kaiwii    1384  0.0  0.0  32000  2336 ?        Ssl  16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//
kaiwii    1392  0.0  1.0 122964 31060 ?        Sl   16:23   0:06 nautilus
kaiwii    1393  0.0  0.1  49268  4904 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 zeitgeist-datah
kaiwii    1394  0.0  0.2  61108  8148 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 bluetooth-apple
kaiwii    1395  0.0  0.2  27848  6576 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
kaiwii    1396  0.0  0.3  40516  9800 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
kaiwii    1404  0.0  0.4  33276 14656 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/bin/python
kaiwii    1407  0.0  0.2  37612  8644 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 gnome-power-man
kaiwii    1408  0.0  0.4 117780 13968 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 nm-applet --sm-
kaiwii    1434  0.0  0.0   3912   244 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /bin/cat
root      1445  0.0  0.1  17720  3696 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/upower
kaiwii    1451  0.0  0.2  55788  7752 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
kaiwii    1453  0.0  0.2  28596  7144 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/notify
kaiwii    1463  0.0  0.1  21816  3336 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/pulsea
kaiwii    1466  0.0  0.1   8300  3244 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
kaiwii    1471  0.0  0.1   9408  3660 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      1473  0.0  0.1  23348  3552 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks
root      1474  0.0  0.0   5564   728 ?        S    16:23   0:00 udisks-daemon: 
kaiwii    1479  0.0  0.0  18204  2252 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
kaiwii    1482  0.0  0.0   8512  2252 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      1528  0.0  0.0   1872   576 tty1     Ss+  16:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
kaiwii    1551  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    16:23   0:00 [zei] <defunct>
kaiwii    1560  0.0  0.0   7716  2228 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
kaiwii    1563  0.0  0.0  22516  2392 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/d-conf
kaiwii    1567  0.0  0.2  59904  7028 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
kaiwii    1587  0.0  0.0   7956  2592 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
kaiwii    1594  0.0  0.0   1912   508 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr
kaiwii    1595  0.0  0.4  36428 12088 ?        Sl   16:23   0:03 /usr/bin/unity-
kaiwii    1598  0.0  0.3  57712  9372 ?        S    16:23   0:05 /usr/lib/bamf/b
kaiwii    1601  0.1  0.6 107724 20028 ?        Sl   16:23   0:08 /usr/lib/unity/
kaiwii    1607  0.0  0.1  61304  5068 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
kaiwii    1609  0.0  0.1 121732  5956 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
kaiwii    1616  0.0  0.1  56888  4104 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
kaiwii    1621  0.0  0.2  60236  7512 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
kaiwii    1630  0.0  0.1  60048  4836 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
kaiwii    1631  0.0  0.1  51984  5464 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
kaiwii    1650  0.0  0.1  18072  3844 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/geoclu
kaiwii    1657  0.0  0.1  27848  5992 ?        Ss   16:23   0:00 gnome-screensav
kaiwii    1658  0.0  0.0  16068  2444 ?        Sl   16:23   0:04 ibus-daemon --x
kaiwii    1659  0.0  0.1  18132  3776 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
kaiwii    1661  0.1  0.8 104216 25696 ?        Sl   16:23   0:09 /usr/bin/python
kaiwii    1663  0.0  0.2  18692  6416 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/i
kaiwii    1665  0.0  0.2  13020  6692 ?        S    16:23   0:05 /usr/lib/ibus-p
kaiwii    1675  0.0  0.2  20120  6752 ?        S    16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
kaiwii    1678  0.0  0.2  59748  8912 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-
kaiwii    1680  0.0  0.1  51144  4256 ?        Sl   16:23   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-
kaiwii    1779  0.0  0.5  34928 17440 ?        S    16:23   0:01 /usr/bin/python
kaiwii    1788  0.1  1.0  73920 31028 ?        Sl   16:23   0:07 /usr/bin/python
kaiwii    1814  0.0  0.4  78052 12824 ?        Sl   16:24   0:00 update-notifier
root      1828  0.0  0.2  14728  8456 ?        S    16:24   0:00 /usr/bin/python
kaiwii    1830 18.0  8.9 648464 269444 ?       Sl   16:24  21:06 /usr/lib/firefo
kaiwii    1866  1.6  2.5 296536 76256 ?        Sl   16:24   1:51 /usr/lib/firefo
kaiwii    1966  0.0  0.0  28220  1184 ?        Sl   16:42   0:00 adb fork-server
kaiwii    2032  1.3  9.4 508608 284896 ?       Sl   16:43   1:19 /home/kaiwii/an
kaiwii    2239  1.2  6.3 777440 190472 ?       Sl   17:00   1:02 /home/kaiwii/桌
postfix   2360  0.0  0.0   5876  1684 ?        S    18:02   0:00 pickup -l -t fi
root      2398  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:11   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root      2399  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:11   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
kaiwii    2419  4.2  0.5  93428 15384 ?        Sl   18:21   0:00 gnome-terminal
kaiwii    2424  0.0  0.0   2068   704 ?        S    18:21   0:00 gnome-pty-helpe
kaiwii    2425  5.2  0.1   7736  4208 pts/0    Ss   18:21   0:00 bash
kaiwii    2480  0.0  0.0   4708  1192 pts/0    R+   18:21   0:00 ps aux
```

Any one can show me which pid or info of the current avd's process? Or, show me any idea to end the avd?

Comment: How do you try to stop it? Do you mean you want to stop a launched emulator? What is the command you use?

Comment: root@kaiwiiho:/home/kaiwii/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ps -ef|grep emulator-5554
root      3000  2968  0 11:32 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto emulator-5554
root@kaiwiiho:/home/kaiwii/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# kill 3000
bash: kill: (3000) - 没有那个进程(the chinese meaning is not such process).So what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run ps -ef | grep avd(or emulator)
then kill -9 (pid of that process)

Answer (score 3):

Running `adb emu kill` is supposed to stop all running emulators if that is what you are trying to stop.

Comment: i try it,but it does not take effect yet.any more idea?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make your console windows full screen. Than you should see more of this line:

```
kaiwii    2032  1.3  9.4 508608 284896 ?       Sl   16:43   1:19 /home/kaiwii/an
```

I guess that your sdk is at `/home/kaiwii/android...` so you should run `kill -9 2032` to kill the process successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
u:~$ ps aux | grep emulator
```

Then:

```
user     2591 72.2  3.4 1016256 142764 ?      Rl   12:25   0:20 /home/user/NVPACK/android-sdk-linux_x86//tools/emulator-arm -avd myavd
```

There is the pid, the emulator-arm line

Comment: well,i have aready try it.but this approach does not take effect.kaiwii@kaiwiiho:~$ ps aux | grep emulator
kaiwii    1925 24.8  6.2 316424 188968 ?       Sl   10:23   0:33 /home/kaiwii/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-arm -avd 8_2.2 -netspeed full -netdelay none
kaiwii    2093  0.0  0.0   4172   856 pts/0    S+   10:26   0:00 grep --color=auto emulator
kaiwii@kaiwiiho:~$ kill 1925

Answer (score 2):

well,here is an approach after carefully reading the detail of the `man kill`.
i should use the command,kill,with the signal 9,for the sake that the process of the off-line avd is hung.